# Phaser games database access

Tags: django, django-models

How do you access database records from Django to be used by a Javascript game development framework like Phaser? I am thinking to serialize into JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Javascript frameworks can communicate through API calls which return JSON just as you assumed. The REST Framework makes this part easy in Django.